# passing arguments between multiple decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using two decorators to decorate a function "add_user", the first one @auth_user authenticates the logged in user via json web token request headers and returns the user's information as an argument "user_info" back to the decorated function add_user. The second decorator @has_permission is supposed to check whether or not the user has permissions on the requested resource. I wanted to pass the user's information returned as user_info by @auth_user to @has_permission but don't know how to do that, here is the code so far:

```
@has_permission
@auth_user
def add_user(user_info):
    """
    do something
    """
    return None
```

The decorators:

```
def auth_user(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        data = jwt.decode(request.headers['some-access-token'], some_secret_key)
        try:
            user_info = User.query.filter(User.id==data['user_id']).first()
        except:
            return jsonify({"message" : "error"}), 401

        return f(user_info, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

and the second decorator where I want to access the user_info:

```
def has_permission(f):
    wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # This is where I want to access the user information instead of processing the key again #
        # return some new_args ... #
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help, I managed to get this working and the main problem was the order/sequence of the decorators. In the question; @has_permission took @auth_user as an argument and @auth_user took the original function add_user as an argument like so:

```
has_permission(auth_user(add_user(user_info)))
```

This would mean that when arguments are returned, the outer most decorator @has_permission would return arguments to @auth_user and then to add_user. This meant that @has_permission could not access user_info returned by @auth_user so I modified the original function:

```
@auth_user
@has_permission    
def add_user(user_info):
    """
    do something
    """
    return None
```

Now the decorators would be called in the correct order like this:

```
auth_user(has_permission(add_user(user_info)))
```

I also changed the way user_info was injected by @auth_user and changed it to kwargs instead of args to access it in @has_permission:

```
def auth_user(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        data = jwt.decode(request.headers['some-access-token'], some_secret_key)
        try:
            user_info = User.query.filter(User.id==data['user_id']).first()
        except:
            return jsonify({"message" : "error"}), 401
        kwargs['user_info'] = user_info
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

And finally passing on the user_info to original function:

```
def has_permission(f):
    wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        #access user info
        user_info = kwargs['user_info']
        return f(user_info, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Hope this helps someone!